# how to export python module where vars have been modified

Tags: python, import, module, export

Suppose that I load dynamically a module from a file with `sys.__import__`, where are defined some variables with values.
Then I modify these 'variables' during execution.
Is there a way to save this new variables as py code in an other file name , like an `__export__(module, fileName)` call ?

Comment: Why dont' you just use environment variables and then use python's os like in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5971635/setting-reading-up-environment-variables-in-python

Comment: I try dynamic code load. In this code, there are variables with initial values. I want to load them (__import__), then run my program with some changes on some variables, and after to save the new state of the module in a dedicated file.