# python in bash: os.environ behaviour

Tags: python, linux, bash

According to [voithos's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5971692/1911722), `os.environ` can set environment variables and subprocess automatically inherit from parent process.

However, compare below to cases

First case, in python interaction mode

```
>>>import os
>>>os.environ['a']='1'
>>>os.system('echo $a')
1
0
```

The result is fine.

Second case, in bash script

```
#!/bin/bash
python3 - <<EOF
import os
os.environ['a']='1'
os.system('echo $a')
EOF
```

save the above as `test.bash` and run `bash test.bash` we got nothing!

Why in the second case, `os.system` doesn't inherit variable?

---

**summary**

Any dollar sign `$` in bash here document will be expanded by default, no matter it is inside single quotes or not.

One way is to escape `$` with backslash `\` like `\$`

There is another way to avoid this expand, that is to single quote the first here doc delimiter, compare following

```
a=0

python3 - <<here
import os
os.environ['a']='1'
os.system('echo $a')
here

python3 - <<'here'
import os
os.environ['a']='1'
os.system('echo $a')
here
```

Comment: Slightly related question: Is your child-process (the python-process) able to set **persistent** environment variables? I know that NodeJS doesn't allow you to set environment variables that persist after the program ends.

Comment: Change `os.system('echo $a')` to `os.system('echo \$a')`

Comment: it inherits variable, but `$a` must be evaluated _before_ because of interactive stuff. I'm using windows and `echo %a%` yields `1` even ran from bash.

Comment: @ChristosPapoulas I got confused. I thought $a only expand inside double quotes. It should not expand inside single quotes, right?

Comment: it's expanded _before_ the command is run, while in the multiline redirect.

Comment: It's not in *shell* single quotes; the single quotes are literal characters inside the here document, which is treated as a double-quoted string by the shell.

Comment: @chepner Thank you for explanation, I understand now

Answer (score 1):

What @ChristosPapoulas says is right. The `$a` is getting evaluated by the shell when you're typing it in. The `$a` never makes it to your python interpreter. This can be seen in the following:

```
$ cat >/tmp/foo <<EOF
> import os
> os.environ['a'] = '1'
> os.system('echo $a')
> EOF
$ cat /tmp/foo
import os
os.environ['a'] = '1'
os.system('echo ')
$
```

Comment: yes, that we saw. But what's the fix? trying `echo \$a` seems to fix it but I cannot test, being on windows.

Comment: Oh. If you write actual python code with a text editor, and put it in a file, then none of this is a problem, because you can put the `$` in the file just fine. Is that an acceptable solution?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre `\$a` works. I am on windows too. But win 10 has built-in sub linux and bash on windows, so I can confirm